# Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream

Tags: java, io, blob

I am getting this error when size of ZipInputStream is more than 1 Gb but it is working fine for 500mb data;

**Java call terminated  by uncaught Java exception: java.lang.RuntimeException:  java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream**

```
conn = (oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)new OracleDriver().defaultConnection();
        newBlob=conn.createBlob();
        InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream();
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(is);
        //get the zipped file list entry
        ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();
        while (ze != null) {
            OutputStream os = newBlob.setBinaryStream(1);
            while (zis.available() != 0) {
                os.write(zis.read());
            }
            os.flush();
            ze = zis.getNextEntry();
        }
        zis.closeEntry();
        zis.close();
```

But if I am using
**newBlob = BLOB.createTemporary(conn, false,oracle.sql.BLOB.DURATION_SESSION);** this, then it is working fine.

Please Help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you have already answered your question. If it works with createTemporary that means your DB connection is getting may be timed out without createTemp method.

Answer (score 0):

Using `InputStream.available()` is not the correct way to detect end of file :
[InputStream.available() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876329/inputstream-available-doesnt-work)