# Copying Jar file without corruption

Tags: java, executable-jar, outputstream, fileoutputstream

I need to copy a .jar file (which is a resource in my project) from a separate runnable jar to the startup folder in windows. Here's the code I have so far.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class Installer {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        InputStream source = Installer.class.getResourceAsStream("prank.jar");
        
        byte[] buffer = new byte[source.available()];
        source.read(buffer);
        
        File targetFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\prank.jar");
        OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
        outStream.write(buffer);
        
        outStream.close();
        
    }

}
```

My problem is that after the jar file is copied, it is corrupt (although the size of the original and the copy are the same.) Any thoughts on how to do this and have a runnable jar at the end of the process?

Comment: Please try with Files.copy() from java NIO.

Comment: `source.available()` returns the number of bytes that can be read without blocking, not the total stream size. Further, `read(byte[])` does not guaranty to fill the entire array; it returns the actual number of bytes read. As Neeraj Benjwal already said, use `Files.copy(source, Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "AppData….jar"));` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [InputStream#available does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876329/inputstream-available-doesnt-work).
The following line

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[source.available()];
```

is not correct, as [`available`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) only return *estimate* of the size, the jar will be corrupted when *estimate* is different with actual. (Example from [Java – Write an InputStream to a File](https://www.baeldung.com/convert-input-stream-to-a-file)) seems incorrect as I can't find any reference that guarantee correctness of `available` for `FileInputStream`.
Solution from [How to convert InputStream to File in Java](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-file-in-java/) is more robust,

```
    private static void copyInputStreamToFile(InputStream inputStream, File file)
        throws IOException {

        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {

            int read;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }

            // commons-io
            //IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);

        }
    }
```

You can consider to use

1. [IOUtils#copy(InputStream, OutputStream)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.io.OutputStream-)
2. [Files#copy(InputStream, Path, CopyOption...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) suggested by *Holger* for jdk 1.7 or above

Comment: Thanks so much! I wanted to learn how to properly use input and output streams so I used this solution. Great answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
    Path source = Paths.get("location1/abc.jar");
    Path destination = Paths.get("location2/abc.jar");
    try {
        Files.copy(source, destination);
    } catch(FileAlreadyExistsException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this tomorrow. I'll let you know if it works.